# How to disable access logs in apache via htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am working on a site and the client wishes users of the non-admin part of the site to be completely anonymous.

I don't know very much about apache, but is there some way to disable logging via the .htaccess file? (so that it can be portable with the site and not reliant on specific server settings)

I've [found instructions](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-disable-and-turn-off-apache-httpd-access-and-error-log/) for the httpd.conf, but I don't know how to replicate commenting out lines in a .htaccess file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer is big NO. You cannot control Apache logging from .htaccess unfortunately.

Comment: That is great to know. The type of answer that tends not to come up through google

Comment: I was frantically trying to enable/disable RewriteLog for some misfiring rule but realized soon that no logging controls are allowed in .htaccess and probably for security reasons since .htaccess owners don't have write access to Apache log directory.

Comment: is it possible to disable logging in the httpd.conf for only specific directories?

Comment: Yes I think that is possible, check this answer: http://serverfault.com/questions/119953/how-to-disable-apache-logging-when-accessing-certain-directories

Comment: Check out the section on Conditional logging, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html

Comment: Thanks so I much. I will check and will modify answer accordingly